# looking for navigation plugin (accordion)

Tags: plugins, jquery, navigation

does anyone know if there's a jQuery-navigation plugin with accordion animation which can be auto-applied to the wordpress default navigation?

it should also support marking the current item (+ also its parent) - any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [DropDown](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dropdown-menu-widget/) Menu. It worked perfectly for me.

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no such plugin, but you could always try with [Wp PageNavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) & [jQuery Accordion plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/accordion) .

By the way is a bit hard for me to imagine accordion animation on page navigation, especially with many pages.